# I get warning Synchronous XMLHttpRequest without set async false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My code call ajax

```
$.ajax({
        url: "<?= base_url('shipping/shipping_data'); ?>",
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            page: 'Shipping'
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.area').html(data);
        }
    })
```

I get warning "[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/"

Comment: It's not this AJAX request that is causing that warning as it's async. However it can also be caused if you have sync content requests within the HTML you add to the DOM from that request (such as `iframe` or `embed` elements with `src` attributes)

Comment: Do you use `$.ajaxSetup()` to change any of the defaults?

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: Wooowww thanks @RoryMcCrossan for fixing it. In the content request I set the src plugin. this is my mistake